# Definition of a matrix by using coaction.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$. Let $C$ be a coalgebra and $V$ a $C$-comodule. Consider the coaction $\delta: V \to C \otimes V$ given by $\delta(e_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij} e_j$. Then we can define the matrix of $\delta$ to be $(c_{ij})_{n \times n}$. Does this definition have some relation with the usual definition of a matrix of a linear map?

The usual definition of a matrix of a linear map is defined as follows. Suppose that $f: V \to V$ is a linear map and $f(e_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij} e_j$. Then we define the matrix of $f$ as $(c_{ji})_{n \times n}$. Thank you very much.

Comment: Here are some reasons why I cannot think of a connection: (1) A matrix that describes a linear map between vector spaces has entries from the field the vector space is defined over. (2) By composition there is a natural definition of multiplication of matrices. This is the same as matrix multiplication which needs a multiplication of the entries in its definition. This is not given for the matrices you describe.

Comment: I am guessing that one can make sense out of a comultiplication of such matrices. This comes from the coassociativity axiom: $$V\to C \otimes V  \to C \otimes (C \otimes V) = V\to C \otimes V  \to (C \otimes C) \otimes V$$
If $C$ is cocommutative, $C\otimes C$ again is a coalgebra. And the matrix you get from the above coaction on $V$ is a matrix with entries in $C\otimes C$ that can be identified with a tensor product of matrices with entries in $C$.